# Java Update not working on Macbook

Tags: macos, software-update, java

I have a Macbook Pro with running OS 12.6.

`/usr/bin/java -version` shows

> java version "1.8.0_341"

> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_341-b10)

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.341-b10, mixed mode)

Since I'm running applications which require a higher Java version ([jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) for instance), I want to update Java. This is what I tried:

I went to SystemPreferences/Java and the Java Control Panel opens.

I go to the "Update" tab.

I would now expect to be shown a new Java version, if one is available. However, on top of the panel is only shown something like a rotating circle, most likely indicating that information is being fetched from the internet. This stays like this for arbitrary time (at least for 15 minutes - after this, I lost the patience). It seems that the Java Control Panel can not access the information from the internet.

Internet connection itself (wireless) works fine. I tried to use the router at home (FritzBox), and I also used tethering via my iPhone as a personal hotspot (and this in turn using mobile data via its SimCard) - just to rule out the possibility that my FritzBox is blocking some ports which are needed for the update.

MacOS Software Update itself works and shows that my Mac is up to date.

Could someone explain why the Java update does not work in this way? Do I have to install a private Java-version in my home directory, if I want to have a more recent one?

Answer (score 2):

Apple stopped supplying Java after Java 6. The Java control Panel was used to control Apple's Java releases and so does not provide later updates.

To get Java 8 you need to install from [Oracle's Java pages](https://www.oracle.com/uk/java/technologies/downloads/archive/#JavaSE). Note that the licence for these might involve some restrictions.

For later Java versions there are several other sources e.g. [OpenJDK](https://openjdk.org/) [Azul](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?package=jdk#zulu)

An easier way to install these versions might be to use a package manager like HomeBrew(although only for the most recent MacOS versions) or Macports.

Answer (score 0):

There were an issue with the Update feature for your verion. Manually updating to a newer version will fix it.

I had the same problem fixed based on the advice in the article below. The update now work again.

"*This article applies specifically to Oracle JRE 8u331 through 8u351 on macOS. Note that Oracle JDK 8 does not provide auto-update and thus this notice does not apply.
Some users who installed Oracle JRE 8 on macOS (on any hardware platform) may experience issues with the Java auto-update feature. This affects Java versions 8u331 through 8u351 (April 19, 2022 through January 16, 2023).*"

ref: https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java8_manual_update_macos.html

[image]